# How to disable save password popup in all browsers using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, passwords, autosave

I have tried every solution I found on the internet. Changed id of password field to "CredentialKey", added `Autocomplete="off"` to both password field and form element, added `AutoCompleteType="Disabled"` to password field, added hidden username and password fields just above the main password field but the browser is still prompting to save password.

Can you please suggest me something? I really need to disable the password popup from code.

Comment: You cannot do this. It is controlled by the client browser, And what about password managers....